# Batch file, removing leading space from folder doesn't work in Win10 but does in WinXP

Tags: batch-file

I am new to writing batch programs. I have thousands of folders that have a leading space character in their name and I need to remove the space. By perusing the Stack Overflow site, I have put together some code that performs as expected in WinXP, but NOT on my Win10 system.

```
@echo off

for /d %%A in (" *") do @for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ("%%A") do @ren "%%A" "%%B"
```

The code snippet above works just fine in WinXP. For example, a folder may be named " L700" but the name gets correctly changed to "L700" after running the code. However, on my Win10 system, the above code doesn't change anything with the filename.

Full code is below:

```
@echo off

rem Prepare environment
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

rem configure where to start
set "root=C:\Test"

rem For each file under root that match indicated pattern
for /r "%root%" %%f in (*,*,*.xlsm) do (

  rem Split the file name in tokens using the comma as delimiter
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%p in ("%%~nf") do (

    rem Test if the file is in the correct place
    for %%d in ("%%~dpf.") do if /i not "%%~p"=="%%~nd" (
        rem if it is not, move it where it should be
        if not exist "%%~dpf\%%~p"  md "%%~dpf\%%~p"
        move "%%~ff" "%%~dpf\%%~p"
    )
  )
)

rem line below removes space from beginning of folder name
for /d %%A in (" *") do @for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ("%%A") do @ren "%%A" "%%B"
```

Comment: I would suggest you remove the first line, and all **`@`** characters, run it again and look at what's happening at your inner, _(second)_ [tag:for-loop].

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion, Compo. I did get it to work, finally. I had been running the code on a memory stick, going back & forth between the two computers. I did get it to work on the Win10 system if it is running from the C-drive, so my problem has been fixed. However, not sure why it worked fine on the XP system running it from the memory stick but not on Win10 from the stick. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you would need such a thing TBH, because it was my recollection that Windows GUI doesn't allow you to create files and directories with leading spaces. So you should be dealing with whatever is naming your files with 'invalid' names, instead of sticking plasters over it. A [tag:batch-file] like this is for repetitive tasks, this should be a rare occurrence!

Comment: Compo - good question. My original issue is that I have thousands of *.xlsm files with names such as "Test File, L700, 2019-08-26.xlsm".  They all have unique L-numbers, and I have some code that creates the L-folder numbers by reading the entire file name. My code is below, but maybe you can point out what I'm doing wrong in the first place, as when I run the code, it puts the leading space in there.

Comment: You mean that it's your fault, because your code is splitting the names at the commas! BTW, where is that code? I cannot see it.

Comment: It is probably my fault, yes. Code is shown above (see the line "for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%p in ("%%~nf") do (....etc
I cannot figure out how to use the delimter to remove the space...

Comment: with `delims=," of course, spaces remain. As you can't do substring processing on `for` variables, you have to assign it to an ordinary variable and remove the space with `set var=!var: =! (of course you need to **en**able delayed expansion for this or use `call set var=%%var: =%% or to `call` a subroutine). Or you expand to `"delims=, "` (and risk unwanted behaviour if there are stray spaces in some but not all file names)

Comment: Yes, I tried the "delims=, " but then it grabs the second word ("File" in the above example "Test File, L700, 2019-08-26.xlsm").

Comment: that's because `delims=xy` doesn't split at `xy`, but on `x` and on `y`. (that's the "unwanted behaviour" I mentioned). If you can rely on the same pattern on each file name (which I doubt, but I don't know your files), you can adapt `tokens=2` to `tokens=3`. Else you have to use one of the other options I mentioned.

Comment: This is a classical [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)! Anyway, your (original) code to remove leading spaces works perfectly on Windows 7 and on Windows XP (tested in VM). Anyway, simply replace the line `move "%%~ff" "%%~dpf\%%~p"` by `for /F "tokens=*" %%q in ("%%~p") do move "%%~ff" "%%~dpf%%~q"` to avoid leading spaces...

Comment: aschipfl - I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. I did modify the last part of your code to %%~p instead of q, as shown here: for /f "tokens=*" %%q in ("%%~p") do move "%%~ff" "%%~dpf%%~p".  Your suggestion renamed the file (an Excel file) to an extension-less file and also created a folder of the same name. The file name did in fact not have a space but the folder it created still has the space.

Answer (score -1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /d  %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\ *") DO (
 ECHO "%%a"
 for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ("%%~nxa") do ECHO ren "%%a" "%%~nxb"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

`ren` command has been disarmed and is simply `echo`ed for safety until script action is verified.

I've no access to an XP system, but I'm surprised it worked on XP. The issue is that `%%a` contains the full path so you need to select only the name and extension for the rename and the leading-space-suppression mechanism.

Comment: Well, in the original code there is no `%sourcedir%` involved in the `for /D %%a in (" *") do` loop, hence pure directory names were returned, so the code worked perfectly fine (tested on Win7 and WinXP)...